# boundary integral estimates for elliptic pde

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider smooth positive solutions $u_m$ of 
$$-\Delta u_m(x) = u_m(x)^p \quad \mbox{ in } \Omega$$ with $u_m=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.   My interest is in obtaining some sort of global integral estimates independent of $m$.   Here $p>1$ and you can assume its close to $1$.    The reason I am asking about integral estimates is that I do not want to apply any blow up arguments.  The real equation has some other terms with parameters that go to infinity;  but they drop out on various integral type estimates.
thanks

Comment: Do you assume that $u>0$ inside $\Omega$? Also why don't you just integrate against $u_m$ and apply Sobolev inequality (should work if $p$ is only slightly above $1$)

Comment: yes i am assuming $u>0$.    Maybe i missing something but I thought this doesn't give me anything.   So i was under the impression the best initial estimate i can get is something like $ \int_\Omega u_m(x)^p \delta(x) dx \le C $ ($C$ independent of $m$) where $ \delta$ is the distance to the boundary.

Comment: then in the case of the above equation one can use some weighted estimates of Souplet, Quittner to start a bootstrap (it is presicely this part is causing problems with the extra advection terms that i didn't add)

Comment: Yes, that is what you obtain from integrating against the first eigenfunction of the Laplacian. However Sobolev tells you that you can estimate some $L^q$-norm with fixed $q>2$ by some close to $1$ power of $L^{p+1}$-norm and, thereby, by Holder by some power of $L^{p/3}$-norm (if $p$ is close enough to $1$), but the latter is controlled by your expression for domains with decent boundary. Am I talking nonsense? (this happens sometimes :lol:)

Comment: i pretty much talk nonsense continuously these days...  If you add a little detail to your above comments I can attempt to see if i understand (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me elaborate. We assume that $\Omega$ is bounded with smooth boundary (this can be relaxed a bit, but we still need something for the naive argument below to work). Let $v$ be the first eigenfunction of the Laplacian normalized by $\int_\Omega v=1$. Then, integrating against $v$ and transferring the Laplacian to $v$, we get
$$
\lambda \int_\Omega uv=\int_\Omega u^pv\ge \left[\int_\Omega uv\right]^p
$$
whence we can control $\int_\Omega uv$ and, thereby $\int_\Omega u^pv$. Since $v$ is comparable to the distance to the boundary, we can also use Holder to control 
$$
\int_\Omega u^{p/3}\le \left[\int_\Omega u^pv\right]^{1/3}\left[\int_\Omega v^{-1/2}\right]^{2/3}\,.
$$
Now integrate against $u$ itself. We'll get 
$$
\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2\le\int_\Omega u^{p+1}=\|u\|_{p+1}^{p+1}\,.
$$
The left hand side dominates $\|u\|_q^2$ with $\frac 1q=\frac 12-\frac 1n$ (Let's say $n>2$, otherwise you can just take any finite $q$ you want).

Thus 
$$
\|u\|_q\le C\|u\|_{p+1}^{\frac{p+1}2}=C\|u\|_{p+1}^{1+\delta(p)}
$$
with $\delta(p)\to 0$ as $p\to 1$.

Let $N=\|u\|_{p+1}$. 
Since $\|u\|_s$ is a logarithmically convex function of $1/s$ (Holder again), we conclude that 
$$
\|u\|_{p/3}\ge cN^{1-\Delta}
$$
with $\Delta=\frac{\frac 3p-\frac 1{p+1}}{\frac 1{p+1}-\frac 1q}\delta(p)\to 0$ as $p\to 1$. Once $\Delta<1$, we can control $\|u\|_q$ by $\|u\|_{p/3}$ and we are done. (I hope that by "integral estimates" you meant some $L^q$ control with respect to the volume measure; otherwise you have to tell me what exactly you wanted).

Comment: thanks you very much for the detailed answer... let me attempt to digest it and see if i understand.

Comment: I think i understand the proof.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Math604 You are welcome. Does it work in your setting or you need something even more robust? In the latter case, just post the actual setup.

Comment: so this was exactly the type of thing i was looking for... now whether it works in my situation might be a problem.  I think unless i can get a $C^{0,1}$ estimate on the first eigenfunction (indepenent of the parameter) this might be a problem.  But i can make some other assumptions (maybe)  to get around this.   So the actually equation i was working with is $ -\Delta u_m(x) + \lambda_m a(x) \cdot \nabla u_m(x) = u_m(x)^p$  where $a$ is smooth and divergence free but where $ \lambda_m \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Math604 OK, let me think a bit then. If I find some way around this, I'll let you know :-)

Comment: actually i haven't thought on whether i really need this eigenfunction bound...was just a thought that if i had it;  then probably everything ok... but it might be okay without it.  I can think on it first and if i have questions i can post more here...in either case thanks for all the help

Comment: @Math604 It looks like you are out of luck (in the sense that you cannot control even the $L^1$ norm) in 1D with constant vector field already. Have you checked this case before? ($\Omega=[0,1], a(x)=1$)

Comment: i was convinced there was some results regarding the case of $a(x)$ divergence free...specially if there as a first integral of $a(x)$. For instance i think there might be some results in (but i can't currently see it)  Communications in Mathematical Physics
February 2005, Volume 253, Issue 2, pp 451–480 | Cite as
Elliptic Eigenvalue Problems with Large Drift and Applications to Nonlinear Propagation Phenomena

Comment: @Math604 I'll check my computation again then (though it looks correct). There may be some chance for *large* $p$ that you can control some $L^q$-norm with $q\le p-1$ but I do not see of what use such low norms may be and you declared that your $p$ is close to $1$ anyway

Comment: Let me ask a related question (since maybe you know the answer off the top of your head).  Consider the original setting.   Now without using a blow up argument (or say moving plane on a convex domain)  i would like to know when we can obtain that $u_m$ is uniformly bounded independently of $m$.    Using the weighted stuff  (which I cannot generalize to the real setting i care about) it seems one obtains the result for $ 1<p<\frac{N+1}{N-1}$.     Using a very slight generalization of your approach (generalize the 3) I think i only get $p<\frac{N}{N-1}$. Is this what you suspect?

Comment: @Math604 Yeah, you need to work more to extend the range. BTW, I checked my computations and stay by my words: you are in trouble for a constant field on $[0,1]$ and I do not see why you should be any better off in higher dimensions. Do you want me to post the details?

Comment: Regarding extending the range;  I am able to do this with a weighted space approach and duality (different than the approach from Quittner / Souplet book);  but i run into problems with the advection term.   Regarding your comment.   So the approach I am using i don't use the first eigenfunction.  I am using a positive `first integral of a(x)' and I assume its roughly linear near the boundary.   I am still a bit confused about what exact estimates regarding the 1D case we are talking about;  so by all means you can type up some details if its easy.

Comment: Let me ask you another question (well its the same question as the original)  but now my interest is in what range of $p$.   For ultra weak solutions we know they are bounded for $p<\frac{N+1}{N-1}$ and if we assume no boundary singularlarities then its bounded for $p<\frac{N}{N-2}$.  Now suppose $u_m$ smooth positive solutions.  Without using moving plane near the boundary (or a blow up argument) is the best one can show that the solutions are bounded for $p<\frac{N+1}{N-1}$ ?    I just figured you might know the answer to this without doing any thinking.  Your help on this is great